# Integrals with complex exponents

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

My text book says that the solution to

$$\int_{-1}^{-1/2} -e^{-i \omega t} dt + \int_{1/2}^{1} e^{-i \omega t} dt$$

is
$$\frac{2}{\omega} ( \sin(\omega)  – \sin (\frac{\omega}{2}))$$

but I can not see how to arrive at that.

What I get when solving the integrals is :

$$\left[\frac{e^{-i \omega t}}{i \omega}\right]_{t=-1}^{-1/2} + \left[\frac{e^{-i \omega t}}{-i \omega}\right]_{t=1/2}^{1}$$

which continues into

$$\frac{e^\frac{i \omega}{2}}{i \omega} 
– \frac{e^{i \omega}}{i \omega} 
+ \frac{e^{-i \omega}}{-i \omega} 
– \frac{e^\frac{-i \omega}{2}}{-i \omega}$$

Reversing the sign of the first two components in this last line would give the correct result using Euler’s identity, but I can not find a justification for that?

Comment: look at what you did. _Carefully_. in fact you dropped a few minus signs

Comment: What happens when you subtract a negative?

Comment: I can only see a solution with the sign of the two first elements reversed. But I still do not see how to justify that...

Comment: Your first two elements are perfectly fine. You are forgetting about the negative signs in the denominators of your last two components. Also, use some intuition here: Each of your components as an i in the denominator. So when you convert everything using Euler's identity you ought to have only i*sin(...) in each numerator so that all the i's can cancel each other out. If the +/- signs are leaving a cos(...) then you will be stuck with i in the denominator.

Answer (score 4):

Key facts:

1. ${\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)}$ i.e. $\sin$ is an **odd function**
2. $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$ i.e.  $\cos$ is an **even function**
3. ${e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\times\sin(x)}$

Let ${z=-t}$, then ${\frac{1}{2}<z<1}$ and ${\frac{dt}{dz}=-1}$. Hence we have
$${\int_{-1}^{-1/2} -e^{-i \omega t} dt = \int_{1/2}^{1} e^{i \omega z} dz}$$

The integral can then be re-written as:

$${\int_{-1}^{-1/2} -e^{-i \omega t} dt + \int_{1/2}^{1} e^{-i \omega t} dt =\int_{1/2}^{1} e^{i \omega t} + e^{-i \omega t} dt}$$

By key fact 3 this can be:$${=\int_{1/2}^{1} \cos(wt)+i\times \sin(wt) + \cos(-wt) + i \times \sin(-wt) dt}$$

By key facts 1 and 2 this can be:

$${=\int_{1/2}^{1} \cos(wt)+i\times \sin(wt) + \cos(wt) - i\times\sin(wt) dt}$$

$${=\int_{1/2}^{1} \cos(wt) + \cos(wt) dt}$$

$${=\int_{1/2}^{1} 2\times \cos(wt)dt}$$

Can you solve from here? (Hint use another change of variable ${z=\omega t}$ and integrate on ${z}$).

Comment: Nice answer!  I would suggest "\cos \omega t " and "\sin \omega t" (put a backslash before sines and cosines).  Also, the symbol "*" is unnecessary.  Add parentheses or brackets where needed:  "[\cos \omega t + \cos \omega t]".

Comment: thank you for this detailed answer! In fact, my text book went straight to your last line, but I wanted to try a direct integration instead. 
I still do not see the error in my reasoning, though. does this mean it is just a "dead end" or did I inverse the signs of my two first components?

Comment: @velsd your answer is fine on the first two components. You are not handling the negative signs correctly in your last two components. Remember you have a negative sign in the denominator (-i*omega). How should you handle adding/subtracting when a negative sign is present?

Answer (score 0):

I think I’ve got it. Starting from the very helpful
$${\int_{-1}^{-1/2} -e^{-i \omega t} dt = \int_{1/2}^{1} e^{i \omega z} dz}$$
we get
$$\int_{-1}^{-1/2} -e^{-i \omega t} dt + \int_{1/2}^{1} e^{-i \omega t} dt
\\=
\int_{1/2}^{1} e^{i \omega t} dt + \int_{1/2}^{1} e^{-i \omega t} dt
\\=
\left[\frac{e^{i \omega t}}{i \omega}\right]_{t=1/2}^{1} + \left[\frac{e^{-i \omega t}}{-i \omega}\right]_{t=1/2}^{1}
\\=
\frac{e^{i \omega}}{i \omega} 
-\frac{e^\frac{i \omega}{2}}{i \omega} 
+ \frac{e^{-i \omega}}{-i \omega} 
– \frac{e^\frac{-i \omega}{2}}{-i \omega}
\\(and \ remembering \ sin(\omega) = \frac{e^{i \omega} – e^{-i \omega}}{2i})
\\=\frac{2}{\omega} ( sin(\omega)  – sin (\frac{\omega}{2}))
$$

Now, this still leaves the original question : how can
$$\int_{-1}^{-1/2} -e^{-i \omega t} dt + \int_{1/2}^{1} e^{-i \omega t} dt
\\=\left[\frac{e^{-i \omega t}}{i \omega}\right]_{t=-1}^{-1/2} + \left[\frac{e^{-i \omega t}}{-i \omega}\right]_{t=1/2}^{1}
\\=
\frac{e^\frac{i \omega}{2}}{i \omega} 
– \frac{e^{i \omega}}{i \omega} 
+ \frac{e^{i \omega}}{-i \omega} 
– \frac{e^\frac{-i \omega}{2}}{-i \omega}
\\=\frac{2}{\omega} ( sin(\omega)  – sin (\frac{\omega}{2}))
\\?$$

In fact, because of the negative sign of the first integrand, I think we have to look at it as designating a “negative area” in the surface described by the two integrals. So its sign can be reversed, and we arrive back at

$$-\frac{e^\frac{i \omega}{2}}{i \omega} 
+ \frac{e^{i \omega}}{i \omega} 
+ \frac{e^{-i \omega}}{-i \omega} 
– \frac{e^\frac{-i \omega}{2}}{-i \omega}$$

Not very intuitive, and I now understand why the text book evades this by (what seemed to me) taking the detour
$$\int_{-1}^{-1/2} -e^{-i \omega t} dt + \int_{1/2}^{1} e^{-i \omega t} dt
=\int_{1/2}^{1} 2\times \cos(wt)dt$$

Thank you for all your thoughts and help!